# PHP Quiz always showing the same result

Tags: php

So I have this one quiz on my page, that tells the user what they might need. It's powered via PHP and jQuery Ajax. The jQuery part is working fine, it displays the result of the quiz on the same page without page refresh, but the php script is not working correctly.

Here's what it should do:

> Check the results of the form, and add or remove a number from the score.

Here's the code:

```
<?php
    $score = 0;
    if ($_POST['muuttuminen'] == 'Kylla'){
    $score - 5;}
    if ($_POST['muuttuminen'] == 'Ei'){
    $score + 1;}
    if ($_POST['possiblecontent'] == 'Kuvagallerian'){
    $score + 1;}
    if ($_POST['possiblecontent'] == 'Pieni verkkokauppa'){
    $score + 1;}
    if ($_POST['possiblecontent'] == 'Isompi verkkokauppa'){
    $score - 1;}
    if ($_POST['possiblecontent'] == 'Jotain muuta'){
    $score + 1;}
    if ($_POST['ulkoasu'] == 'Massasta erottuvan, uniikin ulkoasun'){
    $score + 1;}
    if ($_POST['ulkoasu'] == 'Jotain muuta'){
    $score + 0;}


    if ($score >= 3){
        echo '<p>Sivusi eiv&auml;t ilmeisesti muutu usein, joten ne voidaan toteuttaa ilman julkaisuj&auml;rjestelm&auml;&auml;, ja ne latautuvat nopeammin kuin julkaisuj&auml;rjestelm&auml;ll&auml; toteutetut sivut.</p>';
        }
    if ($score <= 3){

    echo '<p>N&auml;ytt&auml;&auml; silt&auml; ett&auml; sinun pit&auml;&auml; voida p&auml;ivitt&auml;&auml; sivustoasi itse, eli suosittelemme kotisivuja julkaisuj&auml;rjestelm&auml;&auml;n rakennettuna.</p>';
        }

    ?>
```

What I'm possibly doing wrong here?

Comment: You are not *changing* the value of `$score` after the initial assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never set `$score` again (it will always be 0). `$score + 1` does *not* modify `$score`. Either use `$score += 1` or `$score = $score + 1`.

Comment: so like this `if ($_POST['possiblecontent'] == 'Kuvagallerian'){
    $score += 1;}` ?

Comment: Yes. You have to assign the new value to the score variable. I suggest to read the [getting started section in the PHP manual](http://php.net/getting-started)

Comment: Okay, I'll remember this next time!